# Sending the token to server paypal using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, curl, paypal, oauth-2.0

I have successfully acquired a single-use credit card token, i need to send this token to my server to complete the billing process. i will probably want to use Angular's built-in $http module or a third-party REST API library (such as RestAngular) for sending the credit card token to my server.

i use $http module like this:

```
$http({

             url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
             method: 'GET',
             headers: {

                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.accessTokenPayPal,
             }, 

            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         //console.log(data);
                           alert("valide: "+ JSON.stringify(data));

             }).error(function (error) {
                         //console.log(data);
                          alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(error));
             });
```

but i found always this message :

```
{"count":0}
```

what's the paroblem please ??

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Angularjs are you using? Since 1.4 version of angularjs, the $http doesn't support the success and error methods. Please see the deprecation notice at this [link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http). Please use the .then with success and failure callbacks. If this is not the issue with your problem, please give us a detailed error message or a console log message for the call.

Thank you,
Soma.